# Looking for examples of Bazel genrules that generate data files

Tags: bazel

I wanted to make a BUILD rule that depends on a data file which is generated from other files. I tried to write something like this:

```
genrule(
    name = "data",
    outs = ["MyApp/data.dat"],
    cmd = "cd ../libpackfiles ; bazel run FilePacker $(PWD)/../apps/MyApp/data.dat $(PWD)/../apps/MyApp/dataFiles",
)
```

But it didn't work for many reasons. $(PWD) was not recognized by the genrule (the cmd works fine in an equivalent sh script). And I don't know if I am allowed to leave my workspace directory (which is called apps) to do another bazel run command like this.

How could I write a correct genrule that achieves what I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some things to keep in mind when writing genrules:

1. A genrule needs to know all its input files and output files (`srcs` and `outs` attributes)
2. It needs to know the tools it's going to use in the command (`exec_tools` attribute). These tools can be other things that need to be built, like binary targets (cc_binary, java_binary, sh_binary, py_binary, etc), or they can be pre-compiled binaries.
3. The tools have to produce the same files that the genrule declares in the `outs` attribute. It's often easier to declare the files in the `outs` attribute and then pass the file names to the tool using `$(OUTS)` in the `cmd` attribute.

See the documentation for genrule, which includes some simple examples: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#genrule

It would look something like this:

```py
genrule(
  name = "gen_data",
  srcs = [":dataFiles"],
  outs = ["data.dat"],
  exec_tools = ["//libpackfiles:FilePacker"],
  cmd = "$(location //libpackfiles:FilePacker) $(OUTS) $(SRCS)"
)
```

This assumes that `:dataFiles` is a `filegroup` target in the same BUILD file as the `gen_data` target which has a list of files of all the inputs you want to pack. Or it could be a `filegroup` target in a BUILD file in the dataFiles directory, in which case it would be something like `//app/MyApp/dataFiles:dataFiles` (and don't forget to set its `visibility` attribute to `//visibility:public`).

`$(location //libpackfiles:FilePacker)` is replaced with the file path of that target. `$(OUTS)` is replaced with all the files in the `outs` attribute, and similarly for `$(SRCS)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was able to rewrite my rule like this

`genrule(
 name = "data",
 srcs = ["//TheBlackDarkSanctum/res"],
 outs = ["data.dat"],
 exec_tools = ["@libpackfiles//FilePacker"],
 cmd = "$(location @libpackfiles//FilePacker) $(OUTS) -files $(SRCS)",
)`