# Bazel genrule where outputs depend on the input

Tags: bazel, bazel-genrule

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67479973) to [Looking for examples of Bazel genrules that generate data files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67461251) states that "A genrule needs to know all its input files and output files".

Is it possible to write a genrule whose outputs depend on the input file? For example

```
genrule(
    name = "creator",
    cmd = "xargs -a $< touch",
    srcs = [ "meow.txt" ],
)
```

This would create a file for each word in `meow.txt`, e.g.

```
Chico
Groucho
Harpo
```

would create three files.

The list of output files depends entirely on the content of `meow.txt` and is not known in the BUILD file.

Answer (score 1):

That is beyond the capabilities of `genrule`. However, it is possible write a custom rule that [outputs a directory](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/actions.html#declare_directory), into which arbitrary files can be written when the action executes.