# Bazel. Generating files which aren't available prior to bazel build during the build itself

Tags: bazel, swig, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp

I have a problem with building my target, because it needs to build files which aren't available prior to bazel build. I'd like to generate those files during building my target. Problem is that it's hard to tell how many files will be generated.
I want to create bigger monorepo with possibility of build many languages/platforms, for now I stuck cuz I'm trying to use script which uses SWIG to generate cpp/java glue code which are placed in unknown amount of files.
Additionally I need those files to be part of my project tree, cuz I'd like to be able to debug them in runtime and  to have possibility of committing changes in them.

This my proposition of soultion to that problem. (https://github.com/AnDevi/bazel-generating-files-example)

This example (BUILD.bazel) uses only `cc_library`, `cc_binary` and `genrule`.

In `cc_libary` I'd like to compile files which are created in `genrule` via script generator.sh (we need to assume that this script may generate unknown amount files).
Due to that `genrule` can't have directory as output it generates dummy file as output, but the main objective of it is to run script and generate other files.

(`genrule` also works in `local mode` cuz I need to place generated files in my project tree and be able to debug them.)

My `cc_libarary` uses this `genrule` as part of its `srcs`, but another part its `srcs` are files generated by script under the path `source/Generated/*`. Problem is that `cc_libarary` may want to use files under `source/Generated/*` before they will be created and that is why this solution is unfortunately incomplete.

So I wonder if this approach doomed to failure (?) cuz I can't to ensure in any way those files generated by this `genrule` will be ready before `cc_library` will want to use them under the given path.

As different approach I tried to use [aspect-build and run_binary](https://github.com/aspect-build/bazel-lib/blob/main/docs/run_binary.md) but I don't think that it can solve my problem. I tried to run script generating files using `run_binary`, but I failed. Nonetheless there is second reason why I think it's not suitable for my problem, cuz I can't use it in `local mode` (as `genrule`) and due to that I can't add generated files to my project tree.

Maybe there is completely different preferable solution ? Maybe someone else faced similar problem already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution for my problem:

I used this github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk?tab=readme-ov-file#toolsbazel

In this wrapper binary `tools/bazel` I'm running separate step

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash 
$BAZEL_REAL build //target_with_genrule_in_here
$BAZEL_REAL $@
```

before actual build I'm running `genrule` which runs script which creates all files I wanted to create (`genrule` has set `local=True`, so I can create those files in my project tree) and build them in the next step.

Thanks to what I can still achieve all I wanted with calling only one `bazel build` command.

Comment: In general, if a target A needs something from another target B, adding target B as a dependency to target A will tell bazel to build B before A and make the output of B available to A

Comment: If the problem is just that the outputs of the genrule aren't known at analysis time, there are workarounds (e.g. zipping the outputs), but often genrule is not sufficient in these cases. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073133/bazel-genrule-that-outputs-a-directory and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70338029/bazel-genrule-where-outputs-depend-on-the-input

Comment: Yeah, I found this zip solution earlier, but it won't work in my case, cuz then I'd need those files to be unzppied in order to compile them into `cc_library`, so (back to square one) I'd need another genrule which should know ahead what it's needed to unzipped ;D